# Can NodeJS save a session from a website, then act like a browser and navigate said website?

Tags: node.js, session, module, request, cheerio

I am using NodeJS to create a small application to access printer web interfaces on my intranet. I use the `require` module to connect and the `cheerio` module to parse / display the data.

Unfortunately one of the printers uses a log in form (as apposed to html header authentication). I am using the `request.post` function and sending the correct parameters, if this is successful then I find the information in the DOM that I need via `cheerio.load(new url here)` - this however is not successful and I am redirected to the "Session Timed Out" page.

I need to way to keep the session from the initial POST request and then re use that when requesting the new page with the information I need.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, just an idea, if you have fiddler enable, can you try to compare the post request sent from your node app and the post request from a normal browser, see what missing/different?

Comment: Hi @Ming I will try fiddler, I have never tried this before. thank you for your input

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you are storing the session cookie the printer will send back after successful login and including them in all subsequent requests. You can use the [request library](https://github.com/mikeal/request) with the `{jar: true}` option to do this. Make sure you use request to submit the login form, then request to load the next page of HTML, and then pass that HTML to cheerio as opposed to having cheerio load the URL directly as cheerio's request won't include the necessary session cookie.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you for your answer, I have added the {jar:true} and the initial connection is working although I don't know how to access the cookie/session for the second request?

Comment: Just use the same request object to make any subsequent requests and it should have the cookie jar with the cookies. See the request docs for examples.